I need to group by datetime but in specific timezone with EF Core and PostgreSQL
I need to group transaction by its CreatedAt property. But in the specific timezone.
Like this
SELECT 
    SUM("Amount") 
FROM 
    public."Transactions" 
GROUP BY 
    CAST("CreatedAt" AS date) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'

But using EF Core.
I have seen this approach by Mehdi and tried to modify it for PostgreSql.
Here what I have - expression builder:
public class AtTimeZoneExpression : SqlFunctionExpression
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<SqlExpression> _params;

    public AtTimeZoneExpression(IReadOnlyCollection<SqlExpression> parameters)
        : base("notimportant", true, typeof(DateTimeOffset), RelationalTypeMapping.NullMapping)
    {
        _params = parameters;
    }

    protected override Expression Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        if (visitor is not QuerySqlGenerator sqlGenerator)
            return base.Accept(visitor);

        if (_params.First().TypeMapping.DbType == System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset)
            visitor.Visit(new SqlFragmentExpression("CAST( "));

        visitor.Visit(_params.First());

        if (_params.First().TypeMapping.DbType == System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset)
            visitor.Visit(new SqlFragmentExpression(" as date)"));

        visitor.Visit(new SqlFragmentExpression(" AT TIME ZONE "));
        visitor.Visit(_params.Skip(1).First());

        return this;
    }

    protected override void Print([NotNull] ExpressionPrinter expressionPrinter)
    {
        expressionPrinter.Append("AT TIME ZONE Expression");
    }
}

Function:
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static DateTimeOffset ToTimeZone(this DateTimeOffset source, string timeZone)
    {
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
        var date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(source.UtcDateTime, tz);
        return new DateTimeOffset(date, tz.GetUtcOffset(date));
    }
}

ModelBuilder:
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(QueryHelper).GetMethod(nameof(QueryHelper.ToTimeZone), new[] { typeof(DateTimeOffset), typeof(string) }))
            .HasTranslation(args => new AtTimeZoneExpression(args));

And usage:
var activityPerDay = await transactionQuery
            .GroupBy(t => t.CreatedAt.ToTimeZone(timeZoneId).Date)
            .Select(dayGroup => new ItemMetrics
            {
                DateTime = dayGroup.Key,
                Volume = dayGroup.Sum(t => t.Amount ?? 0)
            })
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

I'm using EF Core version 8.0.10.
Here is what I get at
t => t.CreatedAt.ToTimeZone(timeZoneId).Date
(CreatedAt is a non-nullable DateTimeOffset column)

System.ArgumentException: timestamp argument to AtTimeZone had unknown store type NULL (Parameter 'timestamp')

at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.NpgsqlSqlExpressionFactory.AtTimeZone(SqlExpression timestamp, SqlExpression timeZone, Type type, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping)  
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.NpgsqlSqlExpressionFactory.AtUtc(SqlExpression timestamp, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping)  
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlDateTimeMemberTranslator.TranslateDateTimeOffset(SqlExpression instance, MemberInfo member)  
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlDateTimeMemberTranslator.Translate(SqlExpression instance, MemberInfo member, Type returnType, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalMemberTranslatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Translate>b__0(IMemberTranslator t)  
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() 


I have also tried adding NodaTime to context and use translatable functions.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(
    "<connection string>",
    o => o.UseNodaTime())); 

But that also didn't work.

Based on the documentation on Date and time functions and my testing, no additional functions are needed — TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId works as expected. Here’s an example:
var activityPerDay = await transactionQuery
    .GroupBy(t => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(t.CreatedAt, timeZoneId).Date)
    .Select(dayGroup => new ItemMetrics
    {
        DateTime = dayGroup.Key,
        Volume = dayGroup.Sum(t => t.Amount ?? 0)
    })
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

